# Quarkus - decrypt session Cookie of form authentication

Tags: quarkus, java-ee-8

I'd like to read the session cookie in the java quarkus app.

According to this page https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#form-auth, it's possible so we can get access to the information across services.

I'd like to use it to manage all possible sessions of the same user, and add some information, specially for websocket.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to add Security Context to endpoints, like this :

```java
@GET
@Path("/")
public String getSubjectSecured(@Context SecurityContext sec) {
    Principal user = sec.getUserPrincipal();
    // Do stuff with user
}
```

See [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorization)

Comment: So the user principal in inside the cookie then?
is there a way to add custom information inside?

Comment: its identity of authored client, it contains what you need to know who made the call. And if you need more informations, you could augment it. See https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization